# Apache httpd rotatelogs: is it possible to create a new file every day?

Tags: apache, logrotate

I want to make a new logs for my website every 00:00:01 (= each new day).

The problem with rotatelogs is that you can either precise the max size of the logs before creating a new one, or precise the rotation time in seconds. It's not possible to precise *an hour* of rotation.

They talk about "cronjobs", but I don't get it. Could someone please explain if it's possible, and if so, give an example?

Thank you very much

Following is the help of the `rotatelogs` utility:

> / # /opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs --help Incorrect number of arguments
>   Usage: /opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs [-l] [-f]  {|} [offset minutes from UTC]
>
> Add this:
>
> TransferLog "|/opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs /some/where 86400"
>
> or
>
> TransferLog "|/opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs /some/where 5M"
>
> to httpd.conf. The generated name will be /some/where.nnnn where nnnn
>   is the system time at which the log nominally starts (N.B. if using a
>   rotation time, the time will always be a multiple of the rotation
>   time, so you can synchronize cron scripts with it). At the end of each
>   rotation time or when the file size is reached a new log is started. /
>   #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this section of the [manual page for rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/programs/rotatelogs.html):

> ```
>    rotationtime
>           The time between log file rotations  in  seconds.  The  rotation
>           occurs  at  the  beginning of this interval. For example, if the
>           rotation time is 3600, the log  file  will  be  rotated  at  the
>           beginning  of every hour; if the rotation time is 86400, the log
>           file will be rotated every night at midnight.
> ```

setting 86400 as the period will do what you want (new file started at midnight every day).

Also use the -l option if you want  "midnight" to be in your local timezone rather than UTC.

The case when a cronjob would be needed is if you wanted a period of one day but at a different time than midnight. More general tools like [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) (outside apache) are typically used for that.

Comment: From my point of view, if you precise `3600` and you start at `18:30` the next log should start at `19:30`. What I don't get is this: **`at  the  beginning of this interval`**. And the examples they give are not helping: `86400` and `3600`... what if you precise `3660` or `86401`??

Comment: I think the start time of server doesn't play any role. If given 3600 as the rotationtime, the server will divide the unix epoch (number of seconds since 1/1/70 00:00) by 3600 and switch to a new logfile when the remainder of this division is zero (which happens at the beginning of every hour). If given 3660, it would happen every 70mn since 1/1/70 00:00

Comment: If what you say is right (which is probably the case), then the documentation is bad. I'll take a look, write some test cases, then make an article explaining this on my blog. Thanks a lot for your answer! **`=)`**

Comment: @user292916 I was wondering the same thing. Did you ever get around to writing that blog post?